# CSS Issue - ASP.NET Calendar picker

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, dynamic-data

**EDIT**
With one of the below answers, I was able to correct this issue for the rendering within a table.  I'm still seeing this issue within my ListViews.  I've tried this CSS for the ListView, but it has not corrected the issue.

```
/* FIX FOR CALENDAR IN TABLE */
.DateTime_Edit
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.DateTime_Edit table
{
    border: solid 0 #FFFFFF;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.DateTime_Edit table tr td
{
    border: solid 0 #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* LISTVIEW, NOT WORKING */    
.DateTime_Edit table.listview
    {
        border: solid 0 #FFFFFF;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;  
    }
    .DateTime table.listview tr td
    {
        border: solid 0 #FFFFFF;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;  
    }
```

---

**WITHIN A LISTVIEW**
[alt text http://www.imageunload.com/public/15867/CSSIssue2.png?no_history](http://www.imageunload.com/public/15867/CSSIssue2.png?no_history)
**WITHIN A TABLE**
[alt text http://www.imageunload.com/public/15852/CSSIssue.jpg?no_history](http://www.imageunload.com/public/15852/CSSIssue.jpg?no_history)

---

Field Template Definition:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="DateAjaxCalendar_Edit.ascx.cs" Inherits="WarehouseLogging.DateAjaxCalendar_EditField" %>
<div class="DateTime_Edit">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# FieldValueEditString %>' CssClass="droplist"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image runat="Server" CssClass="CalendarIcon" ID="imgCalendar1" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar1"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" CssClass="custcal1">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fltrTextBox1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
    FilterType="Custom, Numbers" ValidChars="/">
</ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="droplist"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="false" />
<asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="DynamicValidator1" CssClass="droplist" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    Display="Dynamic" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to override those styles with another named style.  The new style would need to appear after the style for the table noted above, within the .css file itself. (order of precedence for css is where it appears in the .css file...)  Having a specific style for that control would prevent other styles from doing the same thing in the future.

I wrote this style, placed it at the end of the Site.css file and wrapped my entire "DateTime_Edit" FieldTemplate Contorl in it:

```
.DateTime_Edit
{
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
.DateTime_Edit table
{
    border: solid 0 #FFFFFF !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.DateTime_Edit table tr td
{
    border: solid 0 #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Edit:
Added background-color to the 'td'.
Added !important to everything (may not be needed)

Hopefully the default Site.css file will be updated in subsequent releases.

Comment: This worked for one of the areas the date picker is deployed.  I've added further comments above on the second area I'm seeing an issue.

Comment: Further explanation - when the picker is rendered directly into a normal table, this works, but when its in a ListView, it doesn't.

Comment: in your code above you shouldn't need the "table.listview" entires.  If the .DateTime_Edit style is at the end of the .css file, and wrapped around the entire FieldTemplate control, it should override the other css (unless something else has !Important next to it which I don't see by default).  Try the modified css above.  If that doesn't work, write the css inline using style="".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**

I'd say these guys are the culprits

```
body.template table.listview th, table.gridview th, table.detailstable th, body.template table.listview td, table.gridview td, table.detailstable td
{
}

body.template table.listview td, table.gridview td, table.detailstable td
{
}
```

They specifiy a style to be applied to all `<td>`'s below a table with the class names listview, detailstable & gridview. The problem is they'll be inherited by sub tables as well

You could try, creating a second set of those styles but change them from

```
table.listview td
```

to

```
table.listview td table td
```

and unset any styles that have been applied.
that'll override the styles in the nested tables created by the Calendar Extender

**EDIT**

Ok, It's hard to tell without seeing the entire StyleSheet for the DynamicDataSite Table,
but have a look to see if the CSS For that table is specified using

```
Table
{
   //...
}
TD
{
   //...
}
```

Or using specific .classnames or #Ids

If its the former, you'll need to do some CSS Gymnastics to override the styles for nested tables to undo the styles applied to the main table. e.g.

```
//Top Level Tables
table td
{
    color: Red;
}

//Nested Tables
table td table td
{
    color: Blue
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

Try putting the `CalendarExtender` outside of the table that contains it's target control.
By the looks of it, the `<td>`'s in the picker are inheriting the parent table CSS.

Comment: Agreed - but this being a dynamic data site, I don't control out the field template is rendered.

Comment: Can you post the ASPX for your control where the Extender is inserted into the field template ?

Comment: Just added the CSS for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You may get a clue on how to solve your problem by looking at this post: [[CSS & Overriding Styles on Nested Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773933/css-overriding-styles-on-nested-elements/774016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773933/css-overriding-styles-on-nested-elements/774016).

Comment: Unfortunately, 99% of my users are IE6

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is in the on [DD Preview project here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24887) and is called **AjaxToolkitFixes.css** and is in the root of the website.

Just copy to the root of your site and add a reference in your Site.Master file.