# CSS selector select outer elements only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have below html:

```
 <table class="classA">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And what I would like to do is to format the outer table only, and excluding the table inside.

The current CSS selector I'm using is:

```
table.classA, table.classA th, table.classA td {
    //beautiful css here
}
```

But the above selector would select all the elements inside the table of classA.
So how can I do this?

Comment: As far as I know, there should be 2 levels at maximum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS & Overriding Styles on Nested Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773933/css-overriding-styles-on-nested-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the immediate child selector `>`. And transform your selector into this:

```
table.classA, table.classA > tr > th, table.classA > tr > td {
    //beautiful css here
}
```

This will target only elements that are within a `<tr>` who's direct parent is a `table` with `classA`.

Now, sadly this kind of "has this parent" type of selectors are usually bad for CSS performance (since it has to go up the entire DOM tree and check the element's parents). I suggest a heavy use of classes instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
table.classA, table.classA > thead > tr > th, table.classA > tbody > tr > td {
    //beautiful css here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know, there should be 2 levels at maximum

```
table.classA > *, table.classA > * > th, table.classA > * > td {
    //Css
}
```

Selects all first childs in `table.classA` and second childs `th` and `td`

Answer (score 0):

a simpler approach is to call the desired elements with classes

you transform you html like this

```
<table class="tableclassA">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="trclassA">
         <td class="tdclassA">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="trclassA">
         <td class="tdclassA">
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and then in your css

```
tableclassA, trclassA, tdclassA {
    //beautiful css here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your table inside of the div tag, and then do the stying as given below.
The HTML will now become,

```
<div id="container">
<table class="classA">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Ans then, the styling can be applied to the outer table only by using the following css selector,

```
#container > table.classA, #container > table.classA th, #container > table.classA td {
//beautiful css here
}
```

Note-1: The '>' is used to only select the topmost children in the CSS hierarchy.
Note-2: You can also use class instead of ID on the container div, but the main idea is to enclose inside a parent element.